# Cookies does not work with Chrome, but it's ok with Firefox (localhost)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, cookies, localhost

I have a problem with my cookies. I set and get a cookie in my **local javascript**, and it **works fine with Firefox**. But **Chrome ignore this cookie**. I'll use my local javascript long, and I want to know if we can allow local cookies. 
I simply set the cookie like that:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
}
return "";}
```

And then:

```
setCookie("key",jsonRet.key,1000);
setCookie("login",jsonRet.login,1000);
setCookie("id",jsonRet.id,1000);
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you setting the cookie?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using file://? Chrome does not deal with that though Firefox does.

Comment: Yes, my URL's are like file://. So we just can not set a cookie and get a cookie in a local javascript with Chrome ?